# Работа с HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Нужна помощь. Мне требуется распарсить HTML-страницу после нажатия на ней на некоторую кнопку. Как это сделать с помощью HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: Там всё просто, сейчас 5 секундочек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простой пример парса элементов с тегом "li" на сайте wikipedia, в этой библиотеке есть несколько Get'ов, то-есть можно парсить не только по тегам, а ещё например можно по id'ам и name'ам.

```
    public String GetHTML(String urlAddress)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            return data;

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void parse()
    {
        var parser = new HtmlParser();

        var document1 = parser.Parse(GetHTML("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница"));

        var Tab = document1.GetElementsByTagName("li");

    }
```

---

**НО** лучше сделать как посоветовал **[EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz)**, загрузить просто JSON и его распарсить.

Comment: Вопрос состоял в другом.
Опишу ситуацию так:
1) Я открываю некоторую веб-страницу
2) На ней содержится некоторый контент (текст)
3) Кликаю на этой странице на какую-то кнопку
4) Контент страницы изменяется
Собственно вопрос, как с помощью HtmlAgilityPack парсить изменённую страницу, а не первоначальную?

Comment: https://www.sport-express.ru/football/friendly/clubs/fbl_match-barselona-shapekoense-272552/ - это ссылка на сайт. Там есть кнопка "Протокол". Я хочу парсить страницу после того, как произойдёт нажатие на эту кнопку

Comment: @NickLaptev пойдёт так : вы поставите компонент webbrowser и потом сами нажмёте, а он спарсит? Или там всё должно быть на автомате?

Comment: Надо на автомате

Comment: Блин чё-то сложновато 0_o, он не грузит данных о матче, ну всмысле я в Google Chrome посмотрел, сначала грузиться грубо говоря макет сайта, а потом динамически подгружаются сами данные, я подумаю, но скорее завтра отвечу, просто если честно нет идей насчёт такого продолжительного get'а, но вот парс скажу будет лёгким, простая структура

Comment: Всегда можно найти путь [легче](https://www.sport-express.ru/services/match/football/272552/online/se/?json=1).

Comment: Парс лёгкий, уже пробовал сделать с помощью. Проблема только в отлове правильного контента.

Comment: @NickLaptev кстати EvgeniyZ полностью прав, он json готовенький грузит и всё, а его парсить ещё проще, раз в 10

Comment: @EvgeniyZ скажите пожалуйста, а как вы так его выдернули если не секрет ? :D

Comment: Я уже разобрался. Если кто-нибудь перенесёт вышеуказанный вариант в ответ, то отмечу его правильным.

Comment: @NickLaptev Обновил

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Тут сайт не шифрует данные, можно просто посмотреть в браузере. Скажем возьмем Chrome, жмем F12, вкладка Network и обновляем страницу. Сортируем по столбцу `Type` и ищем `xhr` ну и видим там ?json=1. Некоторые сайты это так явно не выдают и приходится отлавливать запросы через Filder или подобные программы, либо разбирать JS скрипты...

Comment: У сайта кстати есть 2 вида, `JSON` и `XML`. Тут уже что удобнее. Для этого в адресе отвечает конечный `?json=1`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я так же делал, но среди тоны всякого барохла не увидел самой сути, огромное спасибо за такое пояснение )))